# Products visibility and indexer

Tags: magento2, products, visibility, product-reindexing

in magento 2 one of products wasn't visible on front-page. After running command line `indexer:reindex` product is showing. Why do I need run `indexer:reindex` ? In `system -> index management` already settings are "update by schedule", cron is running and in column updated dates are changing. So product should appear automatically?

But... in database in table indexer_state are different dates, and those dates changed when I run `indexer:reindex`. So whats is this table, why is has different dates than in admin (`system -> index management`)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you running your website through cloudflare? also do you have varnish enabled? finally have you tried flushing the cache to see if the dates change? to determain if it is a cache issue